# Pass pandas Dataframe to another script

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to pass a dataframe `df` from the script subscriber.py to algorithm.py.

subscriber.py is collecting data and the output `df` is saved after 5 minutes in memory. algorithm.py should take `df`and do something.

Do you have suggestions how to do this in an efficient way?

*[Currently `df` is saved as csv. The data is appending to the csv and the algorithm.py is running every 5 minutes over the saved csv. After running algorithm.py, the csv is removed and filled with new data. I would like to handover this process in memory.]*

Comment: can't you make a function out of each script and run a third script where the second function takes as input the result of the first one?

Comment: How large is the dataframe? You could run a messaging system like rabbitmq or zeromq or a simple webserver to pass the data in real time. Of course, if the data is too large, you could compress it(have a look at blosc for serious performance).

Comment: I'm wondering if pickling would be faster for you. It is normally slower, though... Could you try using [`df.to_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) and [`read_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_pickle.html) and see if the performance is better?
Also- JSON tends to be pretty fast as well. so you could try it that way instead of using CSV. It's hard to say without the data in front of us